# SonarQube catch 22 with serializable lists

Tags: java, sonarqube

At first I had a class along the lines of:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

SonarQube pointed out that `List`, a member of a serializable class, is not serializable itself. Fair enough, I'll switch to a serializable implementation of `List` like `ArrayList`.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Role> roles;

}
```

At this point SonarQube is unhappy because "roles should use an interface such as 'List' rather than an implementation like 'ArrayList'" which brings me back to where I was originally.

Is there a way out of this loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks your issue was solved just two days ago.

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-808

Comment: Looks like sonarqube guys moved the tracker. New link https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-808